# Does Google Chrome support Silverlight?

Tags: google-chrome, silverlight

Does Google Chrome support Silverlight?

EDIT: I found the download site, ignored the announcement that my system might not support silverlight, downloaded it and tried to install it. It failed.

I don't know where to find the version number of Chrome, but I downloaded, installed and started using it in the last couple of days.

EDIT: Well, I'm still not getting results, so I now use FF for the Olympic channel and it's working. 
When I used it on Chrome, the channel would load and I would get a message saying it wasn't supported, would I like to try it anyway? I click yes and it would work, but after a short time, it would crash Chrome. So, FF.

Comment: It should work (despite not being officially supported) - I haven't had any issues in Chrome 3 or 4 with Silverlight 3. Did you get any error messages at all?

Comment: Just that it failed to injstall.

XP SP3, Branded IBM T60, 4 gig ram.

Comment: You can get the version number of Chrome by selecting the spanner icon and then "About Google Chrome". Chrome also silently updates itself, so there's a near certainty that you're using 4.0.249.89

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TechCrunch: [Silverlight 4 In Beta. Supports Google Chrome.](http://techcrunch.com/2009/11/18/silverlight-4-beta-chrome-facebook/)

> Microsoft announced the availability of Silverlight 4 in beta at its Professional Developers Conference (PDC) today. Some of the new features include more fluid animations, Webcam, microphone and printing support, 200 percent faster start times than Silverlight 3, deep zoom and multi-touch support and more. It now also supports Google Chrome, even though it’s just a [rounding error](http://www.techcrunch.com/2009/09/29/ballmer-microsoft-interview-chrome-windows-internetexplorer/) of a browser.

Some more details on [Silverlight 4 features](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx) and its [Chrome support](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2009/11/18/whats-new-in-silverlight-4-complete-guide-new-features.aspx#google-chrome).
There are also notes of [some success with Silverlight 3](http://chromespot.com/forum/google-chrome-news-and-talk/3189-silverlight.html).

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Silverlight works perfectly fine in Chrome, at least on Windows. No need for any Dev Version or hackery, it works fine in both Chrome 3 and 4, and the released version of Silverlight 2, 3 or 4 Beta works.

Go to http://silverlight.net/, click on Install, ignore the "Your Browser is not Supported" Warning and click on the Windows Download link to download Silverlight.exe, install, you're done.

Comment: +1 It's not officially supported until 4, but I've not had any issues with 3 in Chrome (or indeed Opera).

Answer (score 1):

Support for silverlight on Chrome has been dropped.
The currently chosen answer does not reflect recent developments.

http://blog.chromium.org/2014/11/the-final-countdown-for-npapi.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing Silverlight from Firefox? It's been a while since I installed it myself, but I'm sure I only installed it once (or maybe twice - once from IE and then from Firefox) and it "just worked" in the other browsers.

**UPDATE**

Having had to reinstall everything I can confirm that Silverlight works in Chrome. I installed Silverlight from Firefox and when I browsed to [www.silverlight.net](http://www.silverlight.net) in Chrome it "just worked".

Comment: It installed in firefox when I used that.
I'll try again.

Comment: When I go to that site, there is no download link. I have it installed in FF. Are you suggesting that I just try to use it in Chrome?

Comment: @Xavierjazz - yes, just run Chrome and browser to http://www.silverlight.net and you should see the showcase at the top right.

Comment: Hi ChrisF. I just don't get it. That takes me to apps. I guess my questions is: do I need to install "Silverlight" in Chrome, or do I just start using apps and sites that use it, without installing it in my browser.
Thanks. Don

Comment: @Xavierjazz - yes, just run Chrome and browse to any site using Silverlight and it should show up. I was just using silverlight.net as an example site that I knew had Silverlight on the home page.