# Does Safari on Windows support Silverlight?

Tags: windows, browser, safari, silverlight

Does the latest version of [Safari](http://www.apple.com/safari/) (ver 4) under Windows support [Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/)?

(This question was asked in the spirit of just having this information available on SuperUser after [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/110742/does-google-chrome-support-silverlight) was asked).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Silverlight.net Getting Started page](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/overview.aspx):

> Both runtimes support rich media capabilities and enable fast, cost-effective delivery of high-quality audio and video to all major browsers including Firefox, **Safari** and Internet Explorer running on the Mac or on Windows. The designer experience remains largely the same for both runtimes as well. The main difference resides in the developer experience.

(my bold)

Answer (score 3):

yes.  I went to silverlight.net with it and it worked